# Javascript Function Unpredictable Results in PHP Form

Tags: php, javascript, function, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to use a series of Javascript functions to return dropdown results on different PHP pages. I am getting unpredictable results.

Below is an example of one function. I am calling it (which is located in a separate file) in the body onLoad statement of my PHP pages.

Here is the function (I establish database connectivity with an include file):

```
function SelectMonth(){
<?php
$sqlMonthSelect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ListValues");

while ($month= mysql_fetch_array($sqlMonthSelect)){
echo "addOption(document.form1.BMonth, '$month[ListValue]', '$month[ListValue]');";
echo "addOption(document.form1.AltBMonth, '$month[ListValue]', '$month[ListValue]');";
}?>
}
```

If I have both fields in form1 on the page, I will see the values in both lists. If, however, I only have the BMonth field in form1 on the page (for a quick entry version), I do not see the values in the BMonth list.

I am looking to use the same function to populate different dropdowns on the same page when they exist, and for it to populate whatever dropdowns are present when some exist. I haven't been able to find anything online that reuses the same function like this, but it seems to me like it should work. Is this a problem with JS, or do I have some sort of logic/syntax error?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can you add the resulting JS source? It's easier to debug when we can see the client code...

Comment: This is the only error I see in the consule. It doesn't look connected to the above issue, but I am also not sure of what it means (where the -moz-box-shadow is in my code); I need to check this. Timestamp: 10/18/12 7:45:36 AM
Warning: Unknown property '-moz-box-shadow'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a
Line: 1

Comment: To help you its much easier if you could post the javascript result instead of the generating php. Your problem is probably on the client side, not about php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if there is no document.form1.AltBMonth in the document addOption() should fail as NULL can't have values. Check the javascript console in the browser and see the errors.

Comment: Is it correct to say that when a javascript function fails, the rest of the following functions will not execute? It sounds like this is indeed the reason.